# Running an ssh connection as a daemon

Tags: ssh, python

I am trying to monitor `gerrit` events through an `ssh` command. The command is as follows.

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit stream-events
```

I need to monitor various such `gerrit` instances running on different ports and perform further analysis on the events received from these `gerrit` instances. I want to do it through code using `python`. I considered running these various `ssh` connections as multiple processes, for this I used the `multiprocessing` python package an tried to use the `daemon` attribute to run the process as a `daemon`. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)

while True:
    running = get_runnig_instances() #get all the running gerrit instances
    for instance in running:
        port_num = instance.port
        url = instance.ip
        proc = MyProcess(target=client_setup, args=(url,port_num,)) #client_setup(url,port_num) is a function that runs the command for the ssh connection to stream gerrit events
        proc.daemon = True
        proc.start()
        proc.join()
```

This did not work as after running the `ssh` command for the first `gerrit` instance the control does not come back to the above piece of code from the function `client_setup` and stalls there establishing the connection and waiting to capture any possible events. Thus, any other running `gerrit` instance's events are not captured.

Also, the `get_running_instances` function each time returns a different set of running `gerrit` instances. Thereby, I cannot create the processes all at once.

I also tried to use the `daemon` package to achieve the same. Below is the snippet of the code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import daemon

class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)

while True:
    running = get_runnig_instances() #get all the running gerrit instances
    for instance in running:
        port_num = instance.port
        url = instance.ip
        with daemon.DaemonContext():
            proc = MyProcess(target=client_setup, args=(url,port_num,)) #client_setup(url,port_num) is a function that runs the command for the ssh connection to stream gerrit events
            proc.start()
            proc.join()
```

I faced the same problem here. How do I go about this? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and need help.

Comment: why not use Paramiko?

Comment: I am using paramiko for the ssh connection. The command to be executed when a ssh connection is made, is itself blocking. I used a timeout in join() to make sure the while loop is again executed with different values from get_runnig_instances(). That way present connections are retained and also if any new values, new ssh connections are made. This sufficed my use-case.